# What do you call the player who's scored most goals in a soccer (BrEng ‘football’) championship?

Tags: single-word-requests

I tried translating from Portuguese (*artilheiro*), but only got words related to war like: *gunner*, *artillery man*, etc.

Comment: MVP (Most Valuable Player)

Comment: MVP is usually per-match isn't it, rather than the whole season.

Comment: It depends on the scope but can certainly be used for both : match MVP or season MVP, I don't see why not. Obviously it refers to the best player, not necessarily the top scorer (which could be the word the OP is looking for, even though it's technically 2 words :D).

Comment: I have the impression MVP means the best player of the game/season, but it doens't exactly mean the one who scored most. It could be the goal keeper for instance. Right?

Comment: You are absolutely right, but this was the only 1-word expression I could think of because top scorer requires 2.

Comment: @Martin - in Italian too the player  is called *capocannoniere*, a term that refers to artillery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Top goalscorer***:

> - a ​person who ​scores ​goals for ​their ​team in ​games such as ​football:
>     *Messi ​became Barcelona's ​leading/​top goalscorer that ​season*.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

- [English football first tier top scorers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_football_first_tier_top_scorers)

Comment: I would say "Top goalscorer" (no hyphen)

Comment: I believe top scorer is enough, goal is implied since you cannot score any other way.

Comment: @MorganFR -        both forms are used.

Comment: "Leading scorer" ,"Top scorer"...  I don't think that there's a commonly used colloquial term for this, so the more formal terms would be the best.

Answer (score 2):

**Golden Boot** or **Golden Shoe** is a prize often awarded to the top goal scorer in a competition

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Boot for some examples.

I guess you could use it as a metonym too.